# I'm following a tetris game tutorial with Unity and C# and running into an error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, void

I am following a tutorial to make my first game in Unity. I need some help with the spawner c# code! The link to the tutorial is below.

http://noobtuts.com/unity/2d-tetris-game

Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour {

    // Groups
    public GameObject[] groups;
}
public void spawnNext() {
// Random Index
int i = Random.Range(0, groups.Length);

// Spawn Group at current Position
Instantiate(groups[i],
            transform.position,
                Quaternion.identity);
}
void Start() {
    // Spawn initial Group
    spawnNext();
}
```

I'm seeing an error involving the void in the "public void spawnNext()" line.

Comment: You did not ask a question. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: You never state what error and on what line the error you are getting is. Your question is likely to be closed without more information.

Comment: when i run the program i get a "Parser error: unexpected symbol"

Comment: Where is `Instantiate` method?

Comment: @AlexSikilinda I suspect it comes from [here in the Unity docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a closing curly brace just above your spawn next function. That means you've just closed the spawner class. This is what it would look like if you moved it to the end and actually included all of that stuff in the class:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour {

    // Groups
    public GameObject[] groups;

    public void spawnNext() {
    // Random Index
    int i = Random.Range(0, groups.Length);

    // Spawn Group at current Position
    Instantiate(groups[i],
            transform.position,
                Quaternion.identity);
    }
    void Start() {
        // Spawn initial Group
        spawnNext();
    }
}
```

Try that.

I suspect it's complaining about the "void" because you've just closed that class and it's trying to parse your method definition as a new class (C# doesn't allow floating methods outside of classes). Void is not a valid keyword for classes.

Comment: Thanks for fixing my problem. it helps a lot. thank you

Comment: @cooldude Glad to be of service. If my answer solved your problem could you please also mark it as the answer? Thanks